# drawCircle painting bitmaps?

Tags: java, android, draw, paint

Is it possible to `paint` a `drawCircle` with an image instead of just a colour? If so, how? If not, is there a way I could make it look like there is? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw multiple images onto your `Canvas` and at desired coordinates, like you can draw your circles. Use the [setBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method properly to assign the exact coordinates where you would want the images to be drawn. Here's a sample code :

```
public class MyDrawableView extends View {
private Drawable mD1;
private Drawable mD2;

public MyDrawableView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    Resources res = context.getResources();
    mD1 = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.image1);
    //Set image1 bounds using : mD1.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);

    mD2 = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.image2);
    //Set image2 bounds using : mD2.setBounds(a, b, a + width, b + height);
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    mD1.draw(canvas);
    mD2.draw(canvas);
}
}
```